# How to sync subtitles with video?

Tags: video, editing

If we have an `.srt` and a video file that are out of sync, how to correct it? (Like we would do with Aegisbub on a desktop OS.)

Answer (score 2):

Use **[MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en)**.

It has an option to sync by specifying the time to adjust (in seconds).

Go to **Options (3dots) ->Subtitles-> Synchronization** while playing a video to adjust it..

Comment: Do I have to repeat the correction every time I view the video?

Comment: No, not needed... But make sure **Player->Resume** is enabled